Get list of docker images downloaded for dockerfile FROM clause
I use multistage builds in docker. The first run of docker build on a dockerfile shows that the build image layers are downloaded. Later builds dont downloaded the layers, because they are cached locally.
docker images -a shows only explicitly pulled and locally built images, but not
these, that were downloaded from a FROM clause of Dockerfile.
How to get a list of docker images downloaded for dockerfile FROM clauses?
